# Android ABS Left Padding to ProgressBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have created my custom progress bar style to show an indeterminate bar in the right hand corner of the action bar . Here is my code

```
   <style name="IndeterminateProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"> 
     <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Now i assumed the padding element should add a 5dp padding to the right of the progressbar. But that does not work. It is still stuck to the extreme right of the action bar ? Could anyone please help me.

Kind Regards,